# nnetar return negative forecast values

Tags: forecasting

I am confused about using `nnetar`.

All my training time series data are positive numbers, but the forecast results obtained from `nnetar` returns negative numbers.  The following is my code

```
myts <- ts(data, freq = 5)
fit <- nnetar(myts)
fcast <- forecast(fit, h = 100)
```

However, if I forecast only short period of time e.g., h = 10 or 20.  The returned values are positive.

Did I do anything wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think it's unreasonable to get negative forecasts in this case, you could set `lambda = 0` to achieve strictly positive forecasts.

```
fit <- nnetar(myts, lambda = 0)
fcast <- forecast(fit, h = 100)
```